# How to set enabled state of button via property

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webusercontrol

I am having a user control full of buttons what I want to be able to do is tell each button in turn if its disabled or not so I was using a public enumProperty to allow me to dertmin which button.

```
public enum iandENUM
    {
        Personal =0,
        Property = 1,
        iande = 2,
        Vechiles = 3
    }

public iandENUM actvieButton { get; set; }



<telerik:RadButton ID="rbPersonalDetails" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" Text="Property Details">

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <i class="fa fa-user" style="color: #5bc0de;"></i>Personal Details
                </ContentTemplate>

            </telerik:RadButton>
            <telerik:RadButton ID="rbPropertyDetails" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" Text="Property Details" DisabledButtonCssClass="btn btn-default">

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <i class="fa fa-home" style="color: #5bc0de;"></i>Property Details
                </ContentTemplate>

            </telerik:RadButton>
            <telerik:RadButton ID="rbVechicleDetails" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info"   DisabledButtonCssClass="btn btn-default" btn-defaultText="Vechicle Details">

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <i class="fa fa-car" style="color: #5bc0de;"></i>Vechicle Details
                </ContentTemplate>

            </telerik:RadButton>

            <telerik:RadButton ID="rbincomee"  runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" DisabledButtonCssClass="btn btn-default">

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <i class="fa fa-gbp" style="color: #5bc0de;"></i>Income & Expenditures 
                </ContentTemplate>

            </telerik:RadButton>



            <telerik:RadButton ID="rbPensions" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info"  DisabledButtonCssClass="btn btn-default">

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <i class="fa fa-bank" style="color: #5bc0de;"></i>Pensions
                </ContentTemplate>

            </telerik:RadButton>

            <telerik:RadButton ID="rbMeetings" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info"  DisabledButtonCssClass="btn btn-default">

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar" style="color: #5bc0de;"></i>Meetings
                </ContentTemplate>

            </telerik:RadButton>

            <telerik:RadButton ID="rbOtherAssets" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" DisabledButtonCssClass="btn btn-default">

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <i class="fa fa-share" style="color: #5bc0de;"></i>Other Assets
                </ContentTemplate>

            </telerik:RadButton>
```

This is the class code behind my main question is how would i give a property value so that i can set the active button based on the iandeEnum

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(actvieButton==casesToolbar.iandENUM.Personal)
        {




        }
    }

    private bool _enabledState;
    public bool EnabledState
    {
        get { return _enabledState; }
        set {

            rbMeetings.Enabled = _enabledState;
            rbOtherAssets.Enabled = _enabledState;
            rbPensions.Enabled = _enabledState;
            rbPropertyDetails.Enabled = _enabledState;
            rbVechicleDetails.Enabled = _enabledState;
            rbincomee.Enabled = _enabledState;
             }
    }

    public enum iandENUM
    {
        Personal =0,
        Property = 1,
        iande = 2,
        Vechiles = 3
    }

    public iandENUM actvieButton { get; set; }
    public void disableSectionsTillSave(Boolean isEnabled)
    {

        try
        {
            rbMeetings.Enabled = isEnabled;
            rbOtherAssets.Enabled = isEnabled;
            rbPensions.Enabled = isEnabled;
            rbPropertyDetails.Enabled = isEnabled;
            rbVechicleDetails.Enabled = isEnabled;
            rbincomee.Enabled = isEnabled;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            string inner = string.Empty;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                inner = ex.InnerException.ToString();
            }
            logger.Error("Error in disableSectionsTillSave function edit modules cases " + ex.ToString() + " " + inner);

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the appropriate button(s) when the value of the `ActiveButton` property is modified:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Val1,
    Val2,
    Val3
}

private MyEnum m_ActiveButton = MyEnum.Val1;

public MyEnum ActiveButton
{
    get
    {
        return m_ActiveButton;
    }

    set
    {
        m_ActiveButton= value;

        btn1.Enabled = false;
        btn2.Enabled = false;
        btn3.Enabled = false;

        switch (value)
        {
            case MyEnum.Val1:
            {
                btn1.Enabled = true;
                break;
            }

            case MyEnum.Val2:
            {
                btn2.Enabled = true;
                break;
            }

            case MyEnum.Val3:
            {
                btn3.Enabled = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The property can also be used in the markup, to set the initial state:

```
<userCtl:WebCtl1 runat="server" ActiveButton="Val3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just me, but I see misconception of property usage. The mistake here is that you don't set the property value in it's setter. Should you need access to a property's fields, you write your property like this:

```
private bool _enabledState;
public bool EnabledState
{
    get { return _enabledState; }
    set { _enabledState = value; }
}
```

However, this is now an obsolete way to declare and use a property. Better way is trough so called auto-property:

```
public bool EnabledState { get; set; }
```

Read more about properties in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Later on you can access the property value by accessing the property itself - i.e. `EnabledState` - instead of the property backing field - i.e. `_enabledProperty` in this case.

You set the button's enabled state, somewhere else in your code, by assigning `EnabledState` to their `Enabled` property:

```
        rbMeetings.Enabled = EnabledState;
        rbOtherAssets.Enabled = EnabledState;
        rbPensions.Enabled = EnabledState;
        rbPropertyDetails.Enabled = EnabledState;
        rbVechicleDetails.Enabled = EnabledState;
        rbincomee.Enabled = EnabledState;
```

Unfortunately I can't give you an advice about when and how to determine the `EnabledState` without more details on the business logic. Obviously it should happen before you setup your buttons. One approach would be to run the logic to determine `EnabledState` in `Page_Load`, then in the `Page_PreRender` you setup the buttons.

Comment: Hi boz yes I see my error having see that but what I am wanting is a indivual property for all the buttons if you get me why i thought enum was best way to go

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. Do you mean you want a property for each button? If "yes" - you already have this. Each button has its `Enabled` property. Just use this.